# Is the usage “to not be swayed” in the following sentence proper?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is the use of “to not be swayed” in the sentence "The Court therefore did well to not be swayed by the groundswell of support..."  right ?  (Please see the sentence as the fourth one in the [editorial](http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/2002-salman-hitandrun-case-the-day-ofthe-citizen/article7177624.ece).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's grammatically acceptable but semantically awkward. To *do well* implies that the Court **did** something: it calls for an active verb, not a feeble passive, and a negative passive to boot.

Something like this would be better:

> The Court did well in declining to be swayed by the groundswell of support.

To my mind, however, even that it is dubious. I see no reason to congratulate the Court on achieving what after all is a pretty minimal standard of judicial independence. I'd say simply:

> The Court was properly unswayed . . .